# Adding ngFor value to a (click) function Angular 10

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a table of projects and I want to delete a project by clicking on a button that has referenced the value from a ngFor.

```
<tr *ngFor=" let project of projects; let i = index">
                  <th scope="row">{{i+1}}</th>
                  <td>{{project.projectName}}</td>
                  <td><button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="deleteProject(project.Id)" >Delete</button></td>
</tr>
```

But this doesnt work. `project.id` returns undefined. Any idea?

EDIT: This is what `Projects` contains : [Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X82FS.png)

EDIT 2: Solved. Typo. it was id not Id

Comment: Could you show what you have inside projects array?

Comment: looks like a typo. you have small and a capital letter i in the beginning of id

Comment: @tommueller That was it! Thank you. I feel like im a bit blind sometimes

Comment: If you work with visual studio code I would recommend you the extension "angular-language-service" Just to avoid such mistakes